# Xamarin Forms Android Build issues like already defined with Incompatible format (APT0000)

Tags: build, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on Xamarin forms application, recently updated the packages. The applications is working fine in iOS but not working in Android during building the application its throwing the errors like already defined with incompatible format (APT0000).

Please find the below as same screen shot that I have build errors[image]

So Kindly Please let me know how to overcome from this error.

hank you in advance

Comment: Please post your `vpi_attrs.xml` code, It seems  that you are defining these attributes twice,

Comment: Since you updated the packages in your project, I think the problem appears when different versions of the same library present within the application. Find the libraries that use old versions and update/remove.